# What do the magic item colors mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my travels, I've found numerous magic items.  These items have a color (so far only red, green, and blue).  For example, the Thieves Guild armor (which can't be disenchanted for some reason) is green, items I've enchanted are blue, and some random items I've found are red.

Is there any meaning to these colors (maybe relative power level)? Has the Skyrim Creation Kit shed any light on this?

Comment: Pretty sure they have to do with the "spec" of the enchant in question. For instance, +Health is Red, like your health bar, as is +heavy armor, +melee weapons, +smithing, etc. Alchemy, Stealth, etc, are Green, and most magic things (including shouts) are blue.

Comment: Let me add another color to the mix: I have an armor with orange color that fortifies destruction. Another one was white where the weapon became more effective against the undead. So still not sure what connection is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nils Munch is mostly correct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46351/3389): each enchantment uses one of a number of shader effects (as they're called in the Creation Kit), but the Creation Kit does specify which shader goes with which enchantment.

Categorizing them by color, here's what I found:

#### Blue (Dark)

- Absorb Magicka
- Damage Magicka
- Fear
- Fortify Alchemy
- Fortify Alteration
- Fortify Conjuration
- Fortify Illusion
- Fortify Magicka
- Fortify Restoration
- Muffle
- Regenerate Magicka
- Resist Magic
- Turn Undead

#### Blue (Light)

- Fortify Shouts
- Frost Damage
- Resist Frost

#### Green

- Absorb Stamina
- Damage Stamina
- Fortify Archery
- Fortify Barter
- Fortify Block
- Fortify Carry Weight
- Fortify Heavy Armor
- Fortify Light Armor
- Fortify Lockpicking
- Fortify Pickpocket
- Fortify Smithing
- Fortify Sneak
- Fortify Speechcraft
- Fortify Stamina
- Paralyze
- Regenerate Stamina
- Resist Disease
- Silent Moons Enchant
- Smithing Expertise

#### Orange

- Dawnbreaker
- Fortify Destruction
- Fire Damage
- Resist Fire
- Trollsbane

#### Purple (Dark)

- Resist Shock
- Shock Damage

#### Purple (Light)

- Bound weapons
- Soul Trap

#### Red

- Absorb Health
- Banish
- Fortify Health
- Fortify One-handed
- Fortify Two-handed
- Fortify Unarmed
- Regenerate Health
- Resist Poison
- Waterbreathing

From looking at this list, the colors are, for the most part, intuitive:

- **Blue:** Stuff related to frost, magicka, most of the magic skills, or the undead
- **Green:** Stuff related to crafting or the stealth skills
- **Orange:** Stuff related to fire or destruction
- **Purple:** Stuff related to conjuration or shock
- **Red:** Stuff related to health or the combat skills

Of course, there are exceptions and liberties Bethesda took based on whatever aesthetic choice they decided to make.

There's also the case of items having multiple enchantments: the game chooses only one of the enchantments to display as the effect. However, it's not clear to me which one it chooses: I suspect it's either the first in the internal enchantment list or the last.

Answer (score 3):

Every enchantment has a matching particle effect and reflection filter.

Also the enchantments you might not have access to.

Which colors and strengths that goes with which abilites is up to the Game Designers (Bethesda).

Answer (score -1):

As far as i have understood this its related to the power which is enchanted on it. For example red on a weapon can mean bonus fire damage. Or blue bonus magika or cold damage.

Comment: From my experience there is no connection - the red ones I've found have been mostly fortify combat skills, but I've got a fortify combat skills amulet that's blue and helmet that's green.

Comment: @IanPugsley thats possible. i just made this expirience... but you could test enchantig for example 5 steel daggers with the same enchant and then look if the color is the same. That would give some clarifycation.

Answer (score -2):

every enchantment has its own color like fire=red-orange ice=white